# java.util.Scanner > useDelimiter() in combination with hasNextInt() before and nextInt() after

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am learning Java and stumbled upon something I don't understand.
Maybe someone can explain me why this code

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("78438");
sc.hasNextInt();
sc.useDelimiter("4");
System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
```

has this output: 78438

I would expect it to be like the output of this

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("78438");
sc.useDelimiter("4");
System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
```

or this

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("78438");
sc.hasNextInt();
sc.useDelimiter("4");
sc.hasNextInt();
System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
```

or this code

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("78438");
sc.useDelimiter("4");
sc.hasNextInt();
System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
```

which is: 78

Why is that, am I missing something? I thought the hasNextXXX() methods shouldn't have any effect on the state of the scanner...

Comment: "*I thought the hasNextXXX() methods shouldn't have any effect on the state of the scanner...*" Scanner needs to remember data it red by `hasNextXXX` because some source types like `InputStream`s can be read only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hasNextInt method and other hasNext variants of Scanner cache the next token, so when you call nextInt after hasNextInt, it returns the cached result. You can have a look at the code of Scanner here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/Scanner.java